# Comparing two dotCover coverage reports to find intersection?

Tags: ndepend, dotcover

I've got a bunch of C# code that's covered by both unit tests and system tests. I'd like to find those parts of the code that are covered by both, by only the unit tests and by only the system tests.

I've can generate coverage reports for the two sets (unit tests vs system tests) by using JetBrains dotCover.

How do I compare these two coverage reports?

I've got NDepend, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Roger, with NDepend you can still import several DotCover coverage xml files ([with the right DotCover XML for NDepend setting](http://www.ndepend.com/Coverage.aspx#DotCoverFile)).

*I'd like to find those parts of the code that are covered by both*

Use the Merge Option **AND** as shown on the screenshot below. This will help, it will tell you which method are covered by both tests sets.

If you need to zoom at line by line level covered by both tests sets, unless NCover has tooling for that, you'll need to programatically do the merge of the two coverage files by yourself (it should be not that hard).

[image: NDepend import coverage file]

Comment: Cool. The particular query I want to answer is: "which code is only covered by the system tests?" Is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: Do the AND trick, than make sure to analyze your test assemblies as well as your app assemblies, then write a code query to see who is used transitively from "system tests" assemblies + get covered by tests. You can get inspiration from this default code query to write your own code query: http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Methods_directly_and_indirectly_called_by_test_Methods.html